# Natural topology on space of paths in space with chosen point

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose that $(X, x_0)$ is a topological space and some chosen point. By $\gamma: [0, 1] \rightarrow X$ i call a continuous map. Let's look at the following space $Y$ of all paths:
$$
Y = \{\gamma : \; \gamma(0) = x_0 \}
$$
Is there a natural topology on $Y$? Notice, i am interested in case of abstract topological space $X$, it has no metrics, seminorms or other things.

Comment: [Compact-open topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology) is probably the most natural, defining the exponential object in the category **Top** since intervals are locally compact.

Comment: @user10354138 looks very natural, thanks!

Comment: @user10354138 You should give an official answer, even if it is short.